# Unity3D removing project references in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, sqlite, reference, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am trying to use Mono.Data.Sqlite in my Assembly-CSharp-firstpass project. In MonoDevellop, I right click on the project, edit references, and add Mono.Data.Sqlite to the references. If I build from Mono, everything goes smoothly and and no errors are produced.
When I move back to Unity3D, I always get the error saying that Mono.Data.Sqlite cannot be found. If I then close Unity + Mono and reopen both, the reference to Mono.Data.Sqlite is gone!
Anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after further Googling and Doc reading:
Unity3D rebuilds the project files every time something changes in the Scene/Assets. This means that the added references were being reset and they couldn't be found by Unity.

The solution is to find the needed DLLs (Mono.Data.Sqlite in my case) and copy them to the Asset folder of the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want access to the DLLs you'll want to put them into a folder called "Plugins" in your Assets folder - Plugins are loaded first, so dotnet assemblies in plugins will be avaiable to you when you want to write code against them.

Comment: fun fact: the reference assemblies need to be directly in the Assets folder, not the plugin folder.

Comment: It depends when  you want them loaded.  Plugins load first, so those dlls are available in Editor code as well as game code; Anything in an Editor folder loads next, so it's available in Editor code - but won't be built into the final game.  After that comes the rest of Assets.  So, Assets is fine if you don't want to use the code in Editor, but if you want it in both tools and the game it needs to go to plugins.  You also need to use Plugins if the code is unmanaged.  http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Script_compilation_28Advanced29.html